# Laravel homestead doesn't respond

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant

I just set up my vhost for testing purposes. I've been using vagrant before, but it was for symfony project. The problem is that my server doesn't respond. 
my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/trust_a_skill.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/trust_a_skill

folders:
    - map: c:/xampp/htdocs/trust_a_skill
      to: /home/vagrant/trust_a_skill

sites:
    - map: trustaskill.local
      to: /home/vagrant/trust_a_skill/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I also configuted my system(windows) host file

```
192.168.10.10 trustaskill.local
```

I already have tried curl'ing `http://trustaskill.local:8000/` and `192.168.10.10`
Any thoughts what Am i doing wrong here? I just followed documentation on laravel site. My ssh work's just fine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
vagrant provision
```

in your Homestead folder.

and you might want to check if you use tab instead of space in your Yaml file. Yaml file is so sensitive and it some issues with tabs.

Comment: That's strange. Now i'm getting error: `No such file or directory .../.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I did define file and root to my keys in Homestead.yaml file, why is it looking for id_rsa.pub?

Comment: `../my_project/Homestead` directory

Comment: weird. it should not be complaining about missing file. can you check your Homestead.yml file again. is it the one in ~/.homestead/Homestead.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

After you edit the  Homestead.yaml file  you need to do

```
homestead provision
```

and edit your host file adding

```
192.168.10.10  trustaskill.local
```

in mac

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```